# SQL multiple and get the sum of different joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I need to get the profit of the orders from the real value price and shipment amount with the quantity of the order using the MySQL query.

Please help to find the result using the join queries. order table is the master table of the order data and the inventory table is our price. shipment charge is for calculating the order shipping charge

For reviewing the price details we need to get the sum with our price and quantity of user ordered with shipment charge

Table: order- the master table to list the order data

| order_id | name | order_amount | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | Sunil | 125 | 128 |
| 126 | Kurian | 225 | 129 |

Table: order_item - individual order items details

| order_id | product_id | quantity | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 12 | 2 |  |
| 125 | 13 | 1 |  |

Table: inventory(Individual product actual price )

| product_id | price | itemcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 30 | IKJH |
| 13 | 40 | JUSWK |

shipping_table charge of shipment. As there is a chance for adding the shipping cost in multiple tables with the same amount. I need only one value of one order

| order_id | charge | itemcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 5 | IKJH |
| 125 | 5 | IKJH |

Expected output

| order_id | order_price | actual_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 125 | 105 |

I tried the following query but the result is wrong.

```
SELECT a.created_on ,
              a.order_id,
              a.order_amount,
              sum(c.price*b.quantity),
             
FROM `order` AS `a`
INNER JOIN `order_item` AS `b` ON `a`.`order_id` = `b`.`order_id`
INNER JOIN `inventory` AS `c` ON `b`.`product_id` = `c`.`product_id`
```

INNER JOIN `shipping_table` AS `d` ON `d`.`order_id` = `a`.`order_id`
WHERE `a`.`order_id` = 125
GROUP BY a.order_id
ORDER BY a.order_id

Comment: Show desired output for shown sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual table inside the join for this one.

You can try something like this.

Please check for any performance issues that might arise due to the nature of the virtual table used here. You can make use of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command in mysql to check for performance issues

```
SELECT a.order_id, ordertot.tot
FROM order a JOIN
(SELECT order_id, SUM(order_item.quantity * inventory.price) AS tot FROM order_item JOIN inventory ON order_item.product_id = inventory.product_id GROUP BY order_id) AS ordertot
ON a.order_id = ordertot.order_id
```